# Unable to locate the error in fibonacci series using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write the program for fibonacci series.But I am not able to execute the program.This program is from beginners guide.Can anyone please help me.

```
class fib {
    int fibo(int n) {
        if(n == 1 || n == 2)
            return 1;
        int result;
        result = fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
        return result;
    }
}

class Shruti {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        fib f = new fib();
        System.out.println(f.fibo(5));
        System.out.println(f.fibo(3));
        System.out.println(f.fibo(6));
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run it?  How are you trying to run it?

Comment: https://ideone.com/2Da8Xg

Comment: I am trying to run it on the eclipse, but i am getting output of previous program.Does that make sense.

Comment: (1) Use code indentation. (2) Class names should begin in uppercase. (3) Why create another class, all you need is 1 function.

Comment: Make your `Shruti` class public

Comment: Try my link. If Eclipse outputs your previous program, it does not mean that there is a problem with your current code. So your question is off topic.

Comment: "i am getting output of previous program" Clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo public is the default modifier scope for class.

Comment: @lpratlong No! The default is called *default* or *package*.

Comment: Your code [runs perfectly fine](http://ideone.com/V0Lv9h). Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo Oops, sorry. Yes, you're true :).